# jQuery function to read JSON data. parameter to populate a select

Tags: jquery, json

the title may be not very clear but this is what I need to do.
I have these 2 JSON files:

```
?({
Makes:[
   {
    "make_id":"ac",
    "make_display":"AC",
    "make_is_common":"0",
    "make_country":"UK"
   },
   {
    "make_id":"acura",
    "make_display":"Acura",
    "make_is_common":"1",
    "make_country":"USA"
   },
  {etc...}
]});
```

and

```
?({
Models:[
   {
    "model_name":"Escape",
    "model_make_id":"ford"
   },
   {
    "model_name":"Excursion",
    "model_make_id":"ford"
   },
   {etc...}
]});
```

I want to populate 2 selects:

```
<select id= "dropDownDest">
</select>
<select id= "dropDownDest2">
</select>
```

with a function like these:

```
 CreateSelectFromJson(jsonMakesUrl,"#dropDownDest","Makes","make_id","make_display");
CreateSelectFromJson(jsonModelsUrl,"#dropDownDest2","Models","model_name","model_name");
```

I did something like this, but can't figure out how to pass the last 3 parameters.
This function is only working for Models where I've written the parameters inside the function (they are: data.**Models** where Models needs to be replaced by **nodo** and val(value.**model_name**).text(value.**model_name**) by **parameter1** and **parameter2**).

```
function CreateSelectFromJson(jsonfromurl,idselect,nodo,parameter1,parameter2){
    appendSelectLoader(idselect,"Caricamento..."); //aggiunge un option con il caricamento
    $.getJSON(jsonfromurl,function(data)
   {
     $(idselect + " option").remove();
     $(idselect).prop( "disabled", false );
         $.each(data.Models,function(key,value)
         {
             var option = $('<option />').val(value.model_name).text(value.model_name);
        $(idselect).append(option);
         });

    });
}

function appendSelectLoader(idselect,testo) {
    $(idselect).prop( "disabled", true );
    var option = $('<option />').val("").text(testo);
     $(idselect).append(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the values of your json file, like this

```
function CreateSelectFromJson(jsonfromurl, idselect, nodo, parameter1, parameter2) {
  appendSelectLoader(idselect, "Caricamento..."); //aggiunge un option con il caricamento
  $.getJSON(jsonfromurl, function(data) {
    $(idselect + " option").remove();
    $(idselect).prop("disabled", false);
    $.each(data[nodo], function(key, value) {
      var option = $('<option />').val(value[parameter1]).text(value[parameter2]);
      $(idselect).append(option);
    });

  });
}

function appendSelectLoader(idselect, testo) {
  $(idselect).prop("disabled", true);
  var option = $('<option />').val("").text(testo);
  $(idselect).append(option);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  CreateSelectFromJson('Makes.json', "#dropDownDest", "Makes", "make_id", "make_display");
  CreateSelectFromJson('Models.json', "#dropDownDest2", "Models", "model_name", "model_name");

});
```

[See the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/woCiy1zbtxqflEoZilyp?p=preview)